# Errata database?

Tags: soft-question, online-resources, math-communication, errata

Some authors do a really great job by collecting errors and comments to their books and putting a list on their websites. I wonder if there is some (perhaps wiki-style) website where errata are collected. Does anybody know?

Comment: Similar thread in tricki: http://www.tricki.org/node/406

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/can-matematics-s-e-be-used-to-report-errors-of-a-text-book/12701#12701) on meta.math.SE mentions [Math Book Notes Wiki](http://mathbooknotes.wikia.com/)

Answer (score 12):

There isn't.  This was proposed a few weeks back on the algebraic-topology mailing list.  In response to that, a forum was started to discuss this idea, called the [r-forum](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Vanilla/rForum).  Contributions are welcome.

Comment: Seeing the 7 upvotes on this post, I am somewhat disappointed when I navigated to the r-forum and found it completely empty.

Comment: @WillieWong This was posted in 2009.  It is now 2014.  At some point in those five years, the rForum ceased operation.  At a later point, I migrated all of the forums that I ran, but obviously the rForum didn't migrate properly and no-one's noticed until now!  The old posts are still around - I haven't deleted the database.  If I get a minute I'll figure out what went wrong with the migration.

Comment: ** grumble non persistent links grumble ** Glad I could be of service. `:-)` Offhand do you remember there being any interesting conclusions in that discussion? If there weren't any, then there's little point reviving the link...

Comment: \*\* grumble only me who seems to do this stuff grumble \*\* I think that there was some discussion that would be useful to have archived.  I'll dig it out and get it visible again.

Answer (score 10):

Not quite what you asked for...but useful anyway:  [Mathematical Errata](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~ohagans/errata.php) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120524204525/http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~ohagans/errata.php))

Comment: There are a *lot* more errata than that on the web, though.

Comment: This link no longer works.

Comment: It's too bad this went away.  You can still see it in web archives like the WayBack Machine.  But the last update was 2007.  A reason that errata lists should be in permanent places.

Comment: Here is a [Wayback Machine snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20120524204525/http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~ohagans/errata.php) from May 2012. (I did not find a working snapshot with a later timestamp.)

Answer (score 4):

I think not only for books, but for published papers etc. also there should be errata lists----these could really save many a hair-pulling moment! Moreover, this will make the errata-fixing process public, and because of that probably faster and more transparent.

In fact, it would be great if such a database were created on the stackexchange.com framework, because that works so admirably for MO.

I created a proposal on stackexchange.com, if you are interested please follow it here:

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23788/math-errata-database

Additionally, if someone has a better proposal, I am totally willing to support that too.

Comment: Man, I'm really going back and forth on this one. On the one hand, a StackExchange/MathReviews/arXiv/"errata-base" hybrid site sounds awesome. On the other hand, how would that even work?

Comment: Yeah, I myself have been vacillating for more than a month; yesterday a colleague of mine expressed strong interest in such a site, which impelled me to write this response. I think, because making errata lists is soooo boring (at least for me), such a stackexchange might not be sustainable....especially because the original authors might be either dead, or somehow otherwise indisposed to responding. Hmmm..

Comment: @Suvrit I am proposing some site on the lines I think you were aiming at. Please check it out to see if it is valuable http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90443/math-review

Comment: @ConradoCosta this site might be valuable, but a bit tricky if people end up discussing "work officially under review" and not yet published. In some sense, if Mathscinet would have a "discussion" facility available, that would nail this problem proposed in your area51 proposal...

Comment: @Suvrit I agree, the purpose is to discuss issues and typos on books and published articles. What happened to math errata database proposal?

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I found [Math Book Notes Wiki](http://mathbooknotes.wikia.com/wiki/Math_Book_Notes_Wiki) on wikia network. There still not yet many books, but it seems promising, since it is a public wiki.

According to its front page,

> The purpose of this wiki is to collect clarifications and errata of
>   math texts. People who are learning a subject for the first time have
>   a different perspective on the material than experts who know the
>   whole subject by heart, and consequently are in a unique position to
>   help each other out. If you've got any books around with the notes you
>   made while you were learning from them, please by all means
>   contribute! The more embarassing the misconceptions, the better --
>   these are the things that people don't warn each other about, and
>   consequently cause beginning students a massive amount of grief.

Answer (score 3):

This very recently opened area 51 proposal here at StackExchange could fill this need:

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90443/math-review

It has a broader scope than the 2010 proposal by Suvrit, which didn't make it, perhaps this one will.

Comment: Here is a related discussion on meta.math.SE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21250/math-review-proposal-on-area-51.

Comment: And I should probably also have added link to the relevant discussion on hits meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2396/area-51-proposal-math-review

Answer (score 3):

I have created a [web page](http://mathbookserrata.wikidot.com/home) recently. If you know about any Errata (official or unofficial) leave a comment here after checking it in [mathbookserrata](http://mathbookserrata.wikidot.com/home).

Comment: Rings, Modules, and Algebras in Stable Homotopy Theory is one that I know of. Here is the errata: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/ekmmerr.pdf

Comment: I compiled errata for Barnes and Roitzheim's book Foundations of Stable Homotopy Theory a few years ago. It can be found at https://doronlgn.github.io/Foundations%20of%20Stable%20Homotopy%20Theory%20Errata.pdf.

Comment: @DoronGrossman-Naples: Will that website last forever? if so, lets add it to the list?

Comment: @C.F.G I intend for this website to remain active indefinitely. It isn't associated with a university, so it should remain active as long as GitHub does (unless the authors ask me to take it down for some reason, which I doubt will occur).

Comment: @DoronGrossman-Naples: OK, I've added it to the list.

Comment: @C.F.G The official errata for the fourth edition of Real Analysis, Royden and Fitzpatrick is available [here](http://math.umd.edu/~pmf/docs/Extra_Errat_RA.pdf)

Comment: @Hikaru: Thanks. Has been added.