# Are French, original editions of Grothendieck's EGA&SGA out of sales?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, textbook-recommendation, books

I have been desperately searching for the hardcopies of Grothendieck's EGA and SGA trilogy, but I could not find available sales except for some used books at Amazon with ridiculously expensive prices.  I am aware that there are electronic copies available, but I always prefer hardcopies due to my eye-vision problem.

Are all official publications for EGA and SGA out of sales now?  If not, do you know any foreign website that sells them?  I would love to acquire copies!

Comment: And EGAs can be either downloaded from Numdam, or hardcopies can be ordered directly from IHÉS, see  https://www.ihes.fr/bibliotheque/#publications-mathematiques   (according to the downloadable order form the 8 volumes cost 229 euros).

Comment: How did I not think about trying IHES!

Comment: I believe that  newer versions of SGA1,2,3 are available from SMF: http://smf4.emath.fr/en/CatalogueCommandes/CommandeEnLigne/?page=revue&revue=DocumentsMathematiques

Comment: The "original editions" in your header might be unclear, since I can recall seeing some of the early versions in mimeographed, softcover formats.   The "official" versions of EGA first appeared in IHES volumes (now freely available online at numdam.org as noted by Denis).   In those days I actually wrote to Grothendieck himself asking about availability of his seminar notes with Demazure, and soon a large package arrived in my mailbox at UMass.   That was before email and the internet, of course.    The re-editions may be a better mathematical source now.

Comment: Also, I think almost all Springer LNM are available on demand. This should include SGA. For instance the first: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540369103

Comment: @JimHumphreys What do you mean by "re-editions"?  Where could I get them?  Are volumes from IHES old editions?  By "original edition", I actually meant French publications.

Comment: @A.G  Do Springer LNM print out those electronic files if I request it?  I could not find EGA, though, only SGA.

Comment: @DenisChaperondeLauzières  I have been trying the website you gave to me, but I do not know how I could order the hardcopies from IHES.  It seems that they only operate as library.

Comment: @MathWanderer:  The reference was only to SGA3, which has been re-edited at https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.polo/SGA3/  (whereas older volumes of the IHES Publ. Math. can be found at http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?j=PMIHES (e.g., tome 4).

Comment: @A.G. The Springer website does not offer a printed [and bound] version of SGA, not even through SpringerLink's MyCopy feature. To be precise, they currently refuse to offer MyCopy versions of books not in English. So far I haven't had a good experience with personally requesting print books from Springer, but maybe other people have had more luck. (I never tried to request these specific works, even though I have thought many times of acquiring physical copies.)

Comment: https://www.ihes.fr/en/library/#les-publications-mathematiques-de-lihes  ; look for "Subscriptions and back issues" ; the order form is http://www.ihes.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/PM_BC2017.pdf

Comment: As for the close votes: I think that this is a legitimate question, which more people have. The OP gives a good reason for not being happy about online versions.

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn I recently bought Deligne's equations différentielles ... , but that is all my experience in the last years buying old Springer LNM books in French, so maybe you are right.

Comment: @A.G. But that book is offered as a paperback through the webshop (which is separate from [MyCopy](http://www.springer.com/librarians/e-content/mycopy?SGWID=0-165802-12-557600-0)), SGA 1 is not (at least not in my browser).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn So does Springer refuse to print on-demand copies of EGA and SGA through MyCopy, or should I call them personally?

Comment: @DonuArapura I think first few volumes of SGA are out of print...Is there way to contact them to see if print-on-demand is possible?  SO far, I have not heard back from them.

Comment: @MathWanderer: I once tried asking them to print a book on demand (MyCopy) that was not offered on the website. I think the only reply was just a restatement of the fact that that book is not currently offered through MyCopy, with a vague promise that they might expand in the future. But it's always worth a shot I guess... If enough people in strong enough words complain about the unavailability of a particular book, maybe they will bring it back to life?