# Ideas to face the current publishing issues ?

Tags: ho.history-overview

#### EDIT (Nov. 21, 2011) - follow up

For those who are interested by this question, let me mention that a similar one is discussed quite seriously on [Timothy Gowers' blog](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/a-more-modest-proposal/) (many thanks to r0b0t, who pointed this to my attention in a recent comment).

#### The context

There are many reasons for being unsatisfied with the current situation concerning scientific communication in mathematics. 
Let me summarize a few issues that I consider quite important:

- math journal are expensive.
- there is an increasing number of papers/preprints and the refereeing process starts to be a bit overtaken.
- main preprint archives and review databases do not use the full potentiality of the web.
- journals used to be a tool for communicating results... it is no longer the case and they became a kind of "label of quality" for papers (a more pessimistic way of saying this would be that journals became a tool for a blind management of sciences solely based on a quantitative index).

#### Some answers

With respect to the first issue [John Baez suggested](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/journals.html) broadly to stop publishing in and collaborating with journals that are highly priced. The main drawback of this is that it is not really a collective answer from the math community; moreover, I guess that only established people can allow themselves to do so.

I remember that Greg Kuperberg had a suggestion about publicity of referee's reports, whenever papers are accepted. 
The idea is indeed quite nice but addresses only one issue. My concern here is about a global answer.

#### A proposal

My question is

> How could we (the math community) answer globally, and collectively?

I actually have a naive proposal, which emerged after some discussions with [Vincent Borrelli](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~borrelli/). 
My dreamed answer is a website on which we can find

1. archived preprints and/or links
   to all versions of the same document
   that exists on the web.
2. a discussion page associated to each
   preprint, so that interested people
   can ask/answer questions about the
   paper  (and even suggest
   improvements).
3. a review page on
   which one can find a review of the
   paper. It would be like on
   Mathscinet and Zentralblatt,  except
   that the review is a collective work
   (nobody asks someone do to it).
   There should be rules (the most 
   obvious one is that authors of the
   paper cannot edit the review page).
4. an editorial board having the
   possibility to "publish" some of
   preprints. Here "publish" simply
   means there is  a label on the
   document certifying that the
   editorial board consider the paper
   relevant and (i) either the discussion page converged 
   to a consensus about the  validity of the results, 
   (ii) or the editorial board have asked experts to write reports on the paper, that 
   happened to be positive, 
   and that will be freely available together with the paper.

One can of course imagine having different types of labels (by fields, by standards of quality, by length, etc... like for usual journals), but starting with one would be already great.

Only point (4) cannot be developed with solely "the help of people who want to help". 
Here we would need to start with a board of well-established and famous mathematicians.

My second question is then

> Do you have any suggestion or criticisms to improve this proposal? And would you be ready to help ?

Please just tell me if this is not the place for such a question, in which case I would simply delete it.

Let me add a more funny question:

> How should we cite labeled papers? I.e., do you have a suggestion for the name of this virtual journal ?

EDIT : Thierry Zell pointed [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13619/is-a-free-alternative-to-mathscinet-possible) about a possibly free alternative to MathSciNet or ZB. It seems to me that all the objections to such a project could have been addressed to wikipedia. Nevertheless, I think it is not the heart of my question.

Comment: If you don't have some "standards filter" in place, the site will be overwhelmed with submissions that will not be properly read.  Also, there should be some guard against "self-promoting cliques", where groups of papers are promoted through the system by a group of people whose agenda may not be for the common good.  However, a commentary system which is an adjunct to (something existing like)  arXiv.org could be set up and may be useful, especially if the community was conscientious in moderating it.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.03

Comment: Actually arxiv does link to a commentary system
http://sciencewise.info/

Comment: Gerhard - thank you very much for your comment. I fully agree about filters. Concerning "self-promoting cliques" I have the feeling that publicity is a first guard. 

My idea was not to create something new from scratch. A commentary system adjuncted to arXiv would be perfect. It would satisfies (1), (2) and (3)... the most difficult issue is with point (4). 

Comment: There is a serious discussion to be had about publishing, but this is not it. I don't believe that your depiction of the current situation is accurate: some of what you suggest already exists, and what doesn't already exist sounds impractical. Publishing, both on- and off-line, is more accessible than it ever was. Many journals are expensive, true, but now they're under severe competition from the not-for-profit sector (just look at the editorial boards of  the Mathematical Sciences Publishers journals). Arxiv and blogs have accelerated the transmission of ideas... 

Comment: Zarathustra - thank you for the link. But it seems that the goal is a bit different (as far as I understand well enough their FAQ: http://sciencewise.info/faq)

Comment: There was also on MO a discussion about having free, community-driven alternatives to ZB and MathSciNet, and if I remember correctly, the conclusion was that this was extremely impractical. 

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a rather open-ended discussion and that's not the point of MO.  There are several blogs out there that discuss ways of addressing your questions.  I'm voting to close. 

Comment: As far as I understand, scienceWISE concentrates on annotating PDFs with explanations of the notions used, Wikipedia-style. Or at least this is the only part explained in the FAQ. There are also "report bug" and "report mistake" links, but I have no idea what they do (report bug does not seem to work). This seems too beta to me... Other than that, I very much favor the idea of adjoining discussion boards to arXiv articles.

Comment: Also, hi Damien.

Comment: The difficulty with "dream websites" is not imagining them. Nor is it even creating them. Even if you had money and a talented programmer available, once you have the "dream website", how do you engineer the transition from everyone using the current system to everyone (or rather, just enough) using the new one? This is where all the thought and effort and planning needs to go.

Comment: I agree strongly with the sentiment of the question, but I, like Ryan B, think MO is not the venue for this discussion. Hence I vote to close.

Comment: The ball has been recently picked up by Timothy Gowers: http://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/a-more-modest-proposal/

Answer (score 8):

*These are just some idealistic thoughts about a new type of Website*

Perhaps a combination of arXiv and a heavily modified version of Stackexchange might be worth a try:

**Papers**

- Any User can submit papers, like asking questions here on MO
- Papers containing Errors, previously published results, etc. can be voted to close/delete
- A special System "Edit-Mode" to allow certain User Groups to edit a seperate copy of the paper (correcting mistakes) and allow the submitting User to undo his Mistakes and repost. Furthermore, this "Edit-Mode" will allow other Users to mark passages of a paper as correct.
- Papers will be given Points based on:

  1. The number of times it has been cited
  2. "Upvotes" weighted by the number of "Points" the voting User has
- Papers will be concidered "reviewed" if the entire paper has been marked as correct via "Edit-Mode" by at least X number of Users with >Y number of Points
- *As a rule, papers are only allowed to be cited when they have reached the "reviewed" rank*

**Users**

- Various groups of Users (Profs, Postdocs, Students, etc..). Certain groups need to be verified via PostIdent or some other mean. Users in these groups start out with a higher amount of Points
- Users gain Points by publishing high ranked papers, writing good reviews, resubmitting corrected Papers... (Basically like MO)
- Users can loose Points by plagarism or other wrongful behaviour

Peer-Review would still be in place. The main questions would be:

*Would people bother reviewing other papers?*

If there are enough people in this system, and this system has become the main source of Mathematical Papers, the reviewing process should work. Merely the fact that only reviewed papers are allowed to be cited should be enough to "get the ball rolling". I also believe that the reviewing process will be honest, as it is public. 
Furthermore, like here on MO, humans love achievements. People love gathering "Points", "Exp", or any other sort of trophies. So yes, I think this alone will motivate alot of people.

*How to avoid "double posting"*

As on MO, someone is bound to notice that a certain subject has already been researched. I even believe that this system will be even better stopping plagarism than the current peer-review Process.

The biggest problem would be, to get enough people to join this sort of Website. 
And this last point is why I think, my proposed website will most likely fail.