# Famous papers published in annotated form?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

I very much enjoyed reading through [The Annotated Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Annotated_Turing) which goes through Turing's "On Computable Numbers, with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem" in careful detail. I saw [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122125/math-annotate-platform) on here and while saddened to find an online platform for doing something similar for papers in general has still not materialised, it did get me thinking if there are other books out there that do something similar to The Annotated Turing for other famous mathematical papers. It seems someone's published a similar [book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Annotated_G%C3%B6del/LwpWzwEACAAJ?hl=en) on Goedel's incompleteness theorem just quite recently, so I'd be quite surprised if the list of books annotating famous papers started and ended with these two only.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Annotated_Alice

Comment: Mathiesen, Thomas J., and Euclid. “An Annotated Translation of Euclid’s ‘Division of a Monochord.’” Journal of Music Theory 19, no. 2 (1975): 236–58. https://doi.org/10.2307/843590.

Comment: This is not exactly mathematics, but Green Lion Press has published some books that annotate some classics, such as by [Faraday](https://www.greenlion.com/books/FaradayExp.html) and [Maxwell](https://www.greenlion.com/books/MaxPath.html).

Comment: The Dover edition of Euclid's *Elements* contains extensive annotations by Heath.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem?

Comment: @C. F. G., Fermat's annotated reading of Diophantus' Arithmetica?

Answer (score 8):

H. M. Edwards, "Riemann's Zeta Function" (Academic Press, 1974, New Edition in Dover, 2001) is an extremely annotated reading of Riemann's classical paper on the zeta function).

Comment: Edwards has also written books annotating Galois's original memoir, and Kummer's work on Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: @TimothyChow Edwards being, after all, the person who popularized the phrase "Read the masters!" (quoting Abel) in his article with the same name!

Answer (score 7):

Concerning the book on Gödel's paper ("On Formally Undecidable Propositions of Principia Mathematica and Related Systems"), you apparently meant the book [Gödel's Proof](https://nyupress.org/9780814758373/godels-proof/), which does not seem to be an annotation of the paper, but rather, quoting from the description by the publisher, "a readable and accessible explanation to both scholars and non-specialists of the main ideas and broad implications of Gödel's discovery".

Comment: There is a more recent (2022) annotated version of Gödel's paper: *The Annotated Gödel*, by Hal Prince.

Comment: @JohnStillwell : Thank you for your comment.